# How to unblock a future thread and return results

Tags: rust, hyper

I decided to use the hyper create to build a server that reads the body data of a POST method. [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521201/how-do-i-synchronously-return-a-value-calculated-in-an-asynchronous-future-in-st) explains a part of what I am looking for, but I don't want to use `tokio::run` or `future::lazy` because according to my understanding hyper uses Tokio and futures and the hyper body returns a stream. What I am trying to accomplish is to find other ways of handling a stream and get more knowledge on hyper `Request` methods.

In the first approach, I `concat2` then call `wait`. `wait` blocks the current thread so my code hangs.

```
if Method::POST == req.method() {
    let body = req.into_body().concat2().wait();
    // convert to json and do something with the data.
    Ok(Response::new(Body::from("OK: data submitted")))
}
```

In the second approach, I tried using `poll` and `and_then` but I always get a `NotReady`. The result type is `futures::poll::Async<hyper::Chunk>`.

```
if Method::POST == req.method() {
    let body = req.into_body().concat2().poll().and_then(|e| {
        // do something
        Ok(e)
    });

    match body {
        Ok(e) => println!("{:#?}", e),
        Err(r) => println!("{:#?}", r),
    };
    Ok(Response::new(Body::from("")))
}
```

1. How can I unblock the current thread and return the results?
2. How can I poll and then return the results, ?

If possible, please explain good practice on how to handle `futures::poll::Async` and `wait()`. At the moment, `async`/`await` is unstable in Rust so I can't use it.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm sure you've discovered, calling `wait()` on futures *is an anti-pattern* and defeats the purpose of async IO overall (as you're blocking your thread - and thus the executor - doing so).

`hyper` routes accept a return that implements [`IntoFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0/futures/future/trait.IntoFuture.html), a type implemented for `Option<T>` and `Result<T, E>` in a blanket fashion. As such, what you actually wrote does not need to block at all - you just need to combine futures like so:

```
if Method::POST == req.method() {
   req.into_body().concat2().map(|_body| {
       Response::new(Body::from("OK: data submitted"))
   })
}
```

You don't even *use* the `body` content in your code, but I'm assuming that's for MCVE purposes. Inside the `map()` combinator, that value currently surfaces as `_body` and allows you to do whatever you want with it.

I'm guessing you found yourself in this corner due to the documentation - all the combinators are on the [`FutureExt`](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/futures-api-docs/0.3.0-alpha.19/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html) trait object; they're not defined on `Future` and `Stream` traits themselves. As a result, they will not immediately surface when looking at the 0.2/0.3 doc, and it might have seemed like your only available calls were `poll_next()` and `wait()` as a consequence.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to return the results without using map but use other combinators ? or use the following in the : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237128/cant-read-a-simple-payload-making-http-request-via-hyperclientclient-the-t)

Comment: @Silva you can use any combinator present on `FutureExt` after `concat2()`, as `concat2` implements `Future`. As such, if you need to do more complex things with it, there's a wide variety of them available. Most of the time, however, `map()` (for when you are not chaining into another future), `or_else()` (when you are attempting to recover from an error result) and `and_then()` (when you are chaining into another future) will be the most commonly used combinators.

Comment: The key takeaway is, no matter what combinator chain you decide, you need to return. `hyper` will do the rest by actively polling for it the right way.